# How to replace dataframe columns country name with continent?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe like this.

```
problem.head(30)
Out[25]: 
     Country
0     Sweden
1     Africa
2     Africa
3     Africa
4     Africa
5    Germany
6    Germany
7    Germany
8    Germany
9         UK
10   Germany
11   Germany
12   Germany
13   Germany
14    Sweden
15    Sweden
16    Africa
17    Africa
18    Africa
19    Africa
20    Africa
21    Africa
22    Africa
23    Africa
24    Africa
25    Africa
26  Pakistan
27  Pakistan
28        ZA
29        ZA
```

Now i want to replace the country name with the continent name. So the country name will be replace with its continent name.

What i did is, i have created all the Continent array(which is there in my data frame, i have 56 country),

```
asia = ['Afghanistan', 'Bahrain', 'United Arab Emirates','Saudi Arabia', 'Kuwait', 'Qatar', 'Oman',
    'Sultanate of Oman','Lebanon', 'Iraq', 'Yemen', 'Pakistan', 'Lebanon', 'Philippines', 'Jordan']
europe = ['Germany','Spain', 'France', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Sweden','Czech Republic', 'Finland',
      'Denmark', 'Czech Republic', 'Switzerland', 'UK', 'UK&I', 'Poland', 'Greece','Austria',
      'Bulgaria', 'Hungary', 'Luxembourg', 'Romania' , 'Slovakia', 'Estonia', 'Slovenia','Portugal',
      'Croatia', 'Lithuania', 'Latvia','Serbia', 'Estonia', 'ME', 'Iceland' ]
africa = ['Morocco', 'Tunisia', 'Africa', 'ZA', 'Kenya']
other = ['USA', 'Australia', 'Reunion', 'Faroe Islands']
```

Now trying to replace using

```
dataframe['Continent'] = dataframe['Country'].replace(asia, 'Asia', regex=True)
```

where asia is my list name and Asia is text to be replace. But is not working
it only work for

```
dataframe['Continent'] = dataframe['Country'].replace(np.nan, 'Asia', regex=True)
```

So, help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apply` with a custom function.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
asia = ['Afghanistan', 'Bahrain', 'United Arab Emirates','Saudi Arabia', 'Kuwait', 'Qatar', 'Oman',
    'Sultanate of Oman','Lebanon', 'Iraq', 'Yemen', 'Pakistan', 'Lebanon', 'Philippines', 'Jordan']
europe = ['Germany','Spain', 'France', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Sweden','Czech Republic', 'Finland',
      'Denmark', 'Czech Republic', 'Switzerland', 'UK', 'UK&I', 'Poland', 'Greece','Austria',
      'Bulgaria', 'Hungary', 'Luxembourg', 'Romania' , 'Slovakia', 'Estonia', 'Slovenia','Portugal',
      'Croatia', 'Lithuania', 'Latvia','Serbia', 'Estonia', 'ME', 'Iceland' ]
africa = ['Morocco', 'Tunisia', 'Africa', 'ZA', 'Kenya']
other = ['USA', 'Australia', 'Reunion', 'Faroe Islands']

def GetConti(counry):
    if counry in asia:
        return "Asia"
    elif counry in europe:
        return "Europe"
    elif counry in africa:
        return "Africa"
    else:
        return "other"

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ["Sweden", "Africa", "Africa", "Germany", "Germany", "UK","Pakistan"]})
df['Continent'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: GetConti(x))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Country Continent
0    Sweden    Europe
1    Africa    Africa
2    Africa    Africa
3   Germany    Europe
4   Germany    Europe
5        UK    Europe
6  Pakistan      Asia
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to store your country-to-continent map as a dictionary rather than four separate lists. You can do this as follows, starting with your current lists:

```
continents = {country: 'Asia' for country in asia}
continents.update({country: 'Europe' for country in europe})
continents.update({country: 'Africa' for country in africa})
continents.update({country: 'Other' for country in other})
```

Then you can use the Pandas `map` function to map continents to countries:

```
dataframe['Continent'] = dataframe['Country'].map(continents)
```